# How to sort xml data in c# to get specific data according to value of a element

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

this is my xml ,,

```
    <CruiseProduct>
    <ID>4091</ID>
    <Name>MS ROYAL RUBY NILE CRUISE</Name>
    <Description>
       <p><br>In house music panel.<br>Safe deposit box.<br>All modern and high quality installation and amenities.<br><br><br><b>All inclusive formula</b><br>Breakfast open buffet<br>Lunch open buffet<br>dinner open buffet<br>From 11.00 AM till 23.00 HRS<br>Water (Small Bottle)<br>Soft drinks<br>Local beer (Served by glass)<br>Local wine (Only during lunch and dinner)</p><p><br><b><b>The Program includes:</b><br></b>♦ 07 nights’ accommodation on board of MS Royal Ruby or Similar based on Full Board<br>♦ Return airport transfers in Luxor using Shuttle services<br>♦ Guaranteed upgrade to Main / Middle deck cabins.<br>♦ Complimentary Luxor city tour<b><br><br><b>The Program excludes:</b><br></b>♦ Entry visa to Egypt<br>♦ Tips and personal expenses<br>♦ Any other items did not mentioned above</p><p><b><br></b></p><p><b>Attraction - Combo Light Package</b><br>Visit to the east Bank, Karnak and Luxor temples, Visit the Temple shared by two gods Sobek and Haeroris in Kom Ombo afternoon, Morning visit to High dam, Phila   temple<br><b><br>Attraction - Combo Full Package Excursions</b><br>Visit to the East Bank, Karnak and Luxor temples, Visit the Temple shared by two gods Sobek and Haeroris in Kom Ombo afternoon, Visit Edfu Temple, Morning visit to High dam, Philae temple and unfinished obelisk, on return visits West bank, Hatsheput, Valley of the Kings, Memmon colossi Esna Temple<br><br><b>Attraction - Cruise Signature Program</b><br>Visit Dier-al-Madina + Habu Temple + Valley of the Nobles, Dendra Temple by bus + Temple of Hathor-Cript, Edfu OR Kom Ombo Temple (up to the customer) Kalabsha trip + Botanical Gardens + 01 hour felucca </p>
    </Description>
    <Ref>CMBRUB</Ref>
    <Location>Lux</Location>
    <Images>
     <Image>
     <Name>MS Royal Ruby</Name>
     <Description/>
     <URL>
    http://banks.digital-trip.co.uk/assets/images/packages/c228fa2c-18b1-4c93-    9edc-aa3409d07b7b.jpg
    </URL>
    </Image>
<CruiseProduct>
<ID>4091</ID>
<Name>MS ROYAL RUBY NILE CRUISE</Name>
<Description>
   <p><br>In house music panel.<br>Safe deposit box.<br>All modern and high quality installation and amenities.<br><br><br><b>All inclusive formula</b><br>Breakfast open buffet<br>Lunch open buffet<br>dinner open buffet<br>From 11.00 AM till 23.00 HRS<br>Water (Small Bottle)<br>Soft drinks<br>Local beer (Served by glass)<br>Local wine (Only during lunch and dinner)</p><p><br><b><b>The Program includes:</b><br></b>♦ 07 nights’ accommodation on board of MS Royal Ruby or Similar based on Full Board<br>♦ Return airport transfers in Luxor using Shuttle services<br>♦ Guaranteed upgrade to Main / Middle deck cabins.<br>♦ Complimentary Luxor city tour<b><br><br><b>The Program excludes:</b><br></b>♦ Entry visa to Egypt<br>♦ Tips and personal expenses<br>♦ Any other items did not mentioned above</p><p><b><br></b></p><p><b>Attraction - Combo Light Package</b><br>Visit to the east Bank, Karnak and Luxor temples, Visit the  the Kings, Memmon colossi Esna Temple<br><br><b>Attraction - Cruise Signature Program</b><br>Visit Dier-al-Madina + Habu Temple + Valley of the Nobles, Dendra Temple by bus + Temple of Hathor-Cript, Edfu OR Kom Ombo Temple (up to the customer) Kalabsha trip + Botanical Gardens + 01 hour felucca </p>
</Description>
<Ref>CMBRUB</Ref>
<Location>Luxor</Location>
<Images>
 <Image>
 <Name>MS Royal Ruby</Name>
 <Description/>
 <URL>
http://banks.digital-trip.co.uk/assets/images/packages/c228fa2c-18b1-4c93-    9edc-aa3409d07b7b.jpg
</URL>
</Image>
```

how can I get only the data which location is "Lux" by sorting or however.
that means when a person select "Lux" from select menu, it should appear all the details which only have the Locatin "Lux"

Comment: It is not a correct XML. Can you show the whole XML file?

Comment: You can use XPath, LINQ `Where` or simply iterate through the array and collect this data.

Comment: oh sorry this is part of my xml.could you please give me an example

Comment: Your `CruiseProduct` is not closed. Please, check the question and edit it, if you are missing the line in your XML file. Also, there is no root node. Now, it is impossible to say what format your XML does have and, therefore, impossible to construct queries \ XPath \ code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your xml is well formed you can do it like this.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("abc.xml"); //Load the xml in memory 

root.Elements("CruiseProduct") //Search the details
.Where(x => x.Element("Location")!=null && x.Element("Location").Value == "LUX");//Filter the details based on your criteria.
```

Comment: done, and thanx. but how can I get return data into an array or list.

Comment: Just call .ToList(); after where() clause.